# blur() not working if text is written to input and then erased - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if user has written something to input and then depending on that I'm adding classes `.success` or `.warning`. These classes change only border color. This is my code:

```
$('#myForm input').blur(function (){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
        $(this).addClass('warning');
    }
});

$('#myForm input').keypress(function (){
    if($(this).val() != '')
    {
        $(this).addClass('success');
    }
});
```

If I write some text to input it changes color to green but if I erase that text then the color is still green (and it should be red). Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Comment: you need to remove the classes too warning on success and succes on warning ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens beacuse once you write any value the `class success` is added, then when you erase the content that class is still there and it's still green.

What you need is to remove and add:

```
$('#myForm input').blur(function (){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
        $(this).removeClass('success').addClass('warning');
    }
});

$('#myForm input').keypress(function (){
    if($(this).val() != '')
    {
        $(this).removeClass('warning').addClass('success');
    }
});
```

```js
$('input').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
 $(this).removeClass('success').addClass('warning');
  }
});
$('input').keypress(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
 $(this).removeClass('warning').addClass('success');
  }
});
```

```css
:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.warning {
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
.success {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember to remove the classes you've added. Also, you'll probably find that `keyup` fits your use case better than `keypress`.
There's no need to use two binders, you can join them, I've demonstrated how below.

```js
$('input').on('blur keyup', function () {
  var valid = this.value !== '';
  $(this)
    .toggleClass('success', valid)
    .toggleClass('failure', !valid);
});
```

```css
.success {
  background: limegreen;  
}

.failure {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is alternative CSS only solution that can be used in some cases (but check [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=invalid)). By using `required` attribute you now have ability to style control with [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) pseudo-class:

```css
#myForm input {
  border: 2px #EEE solid;
}
#myForm input:invalid {
  border: 2px brown solid;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type something" required>
</form>
```